# Should lack of workload be a warning sign for something bigger?

Tags: new-job, united-states, manager, workload

so I've been at my new job for about seven months now and have not had much to do. Couple of weeks of getting things settled, finding my desk, meeting people, etc...I was told by some of my senior leads that this was a very busy year with many projects and lots of things that need to be completed yet, everything's gone cold.

I've went to my senior leads about this and was told we'll find you something but never heard from this in months. I brought this up with my manager and showed him my schedule and I haven't done anything since my hire date and was again, told I would be working on something soon. I've volunteered to help any of my colleagues with their work load and most seem too focused on their own projects. I have a performance review next month with a new manager (my current manager is leaving this month). I have NOTHING to show him!

Comment: Could there be a security clearance or citizenship issue?  My first job spent a bit "learning" waiting for a clearance to come. I know people who were not US citizens who got hired but was limited from working on some programs.  Just something to think about.

Comment: Your manager is leaving so have you asked your new manager any of these questions?

Comment: @Ramhound, No, this is a non-ctizenship requirement job so no worries about status.

Comment: @SkywardSword What does your citizenship have to do with anything?

Comment: Is the company restructuring? Maybe work is being offloaded because they plan to restructure the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right to be concerned. This is a long time to not have received assignments or be included on a project team.  I would keep trying to engage your manager and get involved with a team, but definitely suggest looking for your next opportunity. Does not sound like a well-run company from your description. Better to be proactive.

Comment: Surprisingly, this is a fortune 500 company. They had some new hires come in after me who are already getting mentored and working on projects which is aggravating to say the least.

Answer (score -1):

Given the environment you described as busy,you should be concerned.
Probably your manager didn't assign you anything because he is leaving but should have at least assigned you to a project team or a lead to shadow, you can bring up your concerns with the new manager and if situation remains the same after a month start looking elsewhere. Don't wait to get fired.